# Internship in Japan

Tags: visa, japan

I'm an Indian citizen and a final year student pursuing a bachelor degree. I plan to do a summer internship in Japan around May-July.

My official graduation date is June, but I get my physical degree later around August. The visa agent for my company said that neither the internship visa for students nor work visa will be applicable for me in this case, since I won't be a student in midst of the term.

However, I did not find any such rules written on VFS site. Is there really no visa that I can get?

Comment: Are you studying in Japan? Do you have a student visa?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on agents in such cases may not be good enough. The reason is that for a visa agent, it might be the first case they have worked on and they might just say no, just because they might not be knowing. The best way is to get in touch with the Japan embassy/consulate.

You will also find some information at https://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/english/html/travel_and_visa/visa/study-internship.html